# CSS rounded border leaves a gap between border and content

Tags: html, css

I want to have tabs with rounded borders and there is a weird gap between the border and the content. Can anyone help me get rid of it?

[image]

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/borders-on-tabs-95cwzp?file=/index.html

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  zoom: 2; /* just to see it better */
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #133275;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background-color: #9db4d6;
  overflow: hidden;

  /* To reset browser native styles  */
  margin: 0;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
  margin-inline-start: 0;
  margin-inline-end: 0;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}

li {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

li.active {
  background-color: #133275;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li class="active">First tab</Item>
        <li>Second tab</Item>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

A question similar to this one: [Gap between background (or children) and rounded border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71663063/gap-between-background-or-children-and-rounded-border)

Comment: You need to adjust the border-radius of li. The width of ul is bigger so the border-radius of li shows a gap. It's not weird. It is how it is.

Comment: Add margin-left: -1px; to li.active.

Comment: A negative margin also didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question. Using box-shadow instead of border.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  zoom: 2; /* just to see it better */
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #133275; /* added this */
  /* border: 1px solid #133275;  Removed this */
  border-radius: 17px; /* Adjusted from 16 to 17*/
  background-color: #9db4d6;
  /* overflow: hidden; Removed this*/ 

  /* To reset browser native styles  */
  margin: 0;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
  margin-inline-start: 0;
  margin-inline-end: 0;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}

li {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

li.active {
  background-color: #133275;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li class="active">First tab</Item>
        <li>Second tab</Item>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inner element is smaller than outer element, you have to use smaller radius for inner elements.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  zoom: 2; /* just to see it better */
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #133275;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background-color: #9db4d6;
  overflow: hidden;

  /* To reset browser native styles  */
  margin: 0;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
  margin-inline-start: 0;
  margin-inline-end: 0;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}

li {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 13px;
}

li.active {
  background-color: #133275;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li class="active">First tab</Item>
        <li>Second tab</Item>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does not change the background/not fully filling the UL - try zooming your browser to say 125%

Comment: Thanks, @Jonu, I played with the border values. It improves a little but it still does not fix the issue as mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: @Fernando I posted another solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `<li>` element is a tiny bit smaller than the parent `<ul>`.
Border raidus is calculated from the size of the element. You got two different sized elements so when it's calculated here ( math with pi ), that tiny bit gets noticable.

To see what I'm talking about, remove the border-radius of the aforementioned `<li>` element.

To solve your problem increase the border-radius of either `<li>` or `<ul>`. This will produce different results, so pick your poison.

You can also change the background-color to

`background: linear-gradient(to right, #133275 10%, #9db4d6 50%);`

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, @souljack I tried different border sizes, but still, no luck as mentioned in my comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/72447733/3765819. The gradient background does not cover the case when the second tab is active.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the sandbox that's causing you problems? 
I've succeded in solving your problem, in the sandbox, by using outline instead of border and adding an offset of -1. Border radius can then stay the same.<>

  outline: 1px solid #133275;
  outline-offset: -1px;

Comment: Thanks, @Souljack That might be another solution but you didn't mention that in your initial answer. I was able to reproduce the issue on different browsers. But I did solve it with my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72451304/3765819

Answer (score 0):

J just "Remove" Border from "ul" tag and add in "li" tag. then for active "li" i use "#133275" this color and non active use "#9db4d6" this border color. and your space issue is solve.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  zoom: 2; /* just to see it better */
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background-color: #9db4d6;
  overflow: hidden;

  /* To reset browser native styeld  */
  margin: 0;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
  margin-inline-start: 0;
  margin-inline-end: 0;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}

li {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 16px;
      border: 1px solid #9db4d6;
}

li.active {
  background-color: #133275;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #133275;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link href="src/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <ul>
            <li class="active">First tab</Item>
            <li>Second tab</Item>
        </ul>
  </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Satish Modha, that still doesn't fix the issue. If you notice, the border on the ul not the same color and the example on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is remove first and last childs radius from outer side, because you have overflow hidden in ul. If you have three or more elements, all elements between first and last have fully rounded corners.

```css
   body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      zoom: 2; /* just to see it better */
    }

    ul {
      list-style: none;
      display: flex;
      display: flex;
      list-style: none;
      border: 1px solid #133275;
      border-radius: 16px;
      background-color: #9db4d6;
      overflow: hidden;
      /* To reset browser native styles  */
      margin: 0;
      margin-block-start: 0;
      margin-block-end: 0;
      margin-inline-start: 0;
      margin-inline-end: 0;
      padding-inline-start: 0;
    }

    li {
      padding: 6px 12px;
      font-size: 20px;
      border-radius: 13px;
    }

    li.active {
      background-color: #133275;
      color: white;
    }

    ul li:first-child {
      border-radius: 0 16px 16px 0;
    }
    ul li:last-child {
      border-radius:16px 0 0 16px;
    }


**Two tabs:**
```

```html
         <div class="container">
         <ul>
            <li>First tab</li>
            <li class="active">Second tab</li>
          </ul>
</div>




         <div class="container">
         <ul>
            <li>First tab</li>
            <li>Second tab</li>
            <li class="active">Third tab</li>
            <li>Fourth tab</li>
          </ul>
</div>
```